# How to configure Postfix to use multiple IP aliases for sending out email?

Tags: postfix

Running Postfix on Linux.

I know how to create IP aliases.

I know how to create multiple smtp transports and bind them to various IPs:

```
smtp_bind_address=X.Y.Z.Q
```

I know how to assign a transport to a specific recipient domain:

```
# cat transport
yahoo.com    yahoo:
gmail.com    gmail:
```

What I don't know is how to get Postfix to use multiple transports for a single recipient domain, each transport bound to a different IP. If that was possible, I could create several IP aliases, bind a transport to each, and spread delivery to a specific domain over all those aliases.

The reason I want to do this is that some ISPs are exceedingly slow to take in emails. 75% of our emails are delivered very quickly, but then there's this straggler ISP who has a lot of recipients but takes a very very long time on the intake because they are throttling everything down a lot, per sender IP.

Comment: Not easily. You'll need some kludges. http://serverfault.com/q/288349/126632